# Changing Dropdown selections for my product selection to Radio buttons to select products on my products page

Tags: radio-button

Currently, my shop has a dropdown button for selecting different products and I want to change it to the Radio button option. I'm new at this so I'm not sure if that makes sense. But when you are viewing one of my VARIABLE products and want to select which quantity to purchase, there is a dropdown button that has the options. For example, 6, 1-pint bottles, 6, 1-quart bottles, or 2, 1-gallon containers. These are on a dropdown list and the user has to click scroll to make a selection. I want the options to be visible where the customer can just click their preferred option. I think it's called Radio Button. My main question is: do I have to install a plugin to get this option in my woo-commerce store on WordPress or can I manipulate the HTML coding? If I can manipulate the coding, where do I find the code for that?

woo-commerce/WordPress has an option to use additional CSS to override coding. I used that for hiding the "additional information" section on my products page. But I couldn't get any code to work for creating the radio buttons. Perhaps I didn't use the right code. If anyone knows, please help. I used a few variations of the following code in my own attempt: .choose_an_option_tab {display: radio_button !important; }

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: Neither the technology nor the code is explicitly clear. Please add the matching tags, format any code in your post and/or provide a link to your shop/add some sample code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Arman, thank you for the comment. I actually just went with a plugin that works for now. It appears that replacing the code in WordPress is more advanced than I'm able to work with at this time. I don't have the knowledge or resources for that at this time. I will just go with the plugin for now. Thanks again!